# Not sure why extending/injecting an instance method in to a lua object isn't working

Tags: lua

In this example, I'm using [`lunit`](https://github.com/dcurrie/lunit) and am attempting to inject an instance method in to an instance of [`LuaSocket`](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket) and am failing to see why the following isn't working.

```lua
-- Using lunit for unit testing
local lunit = require('lunitx')
_ENV = lunit.module('enhanced', 'seeall')

local socket = require('socket')

-- connect(2) to the service tcp/echo
local conn, connErr = socket.connect('127.0.0.1', '7')

function conn:receiveLine(...)
    local line, err = self:receive('*l')
    assert_string(line, err)
    return line
end

function conn:sendLine(...)
    local bytesSent, err = self:send(... .. '\n')
    assert_number(bytesSent, err)
    return bytesSent
end
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```lua
attempt to call method 'sendLine' (a nil value)
```

?? This seems like there is something obvious happening here, but I'm missing the required detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ass-u-me'ing `getmetatable(conn).__index` == `getmetatable(conn)` source of confusion.

In this case, `conn`'s metatable's `__index` metamethod is pointing to a different table than expected, so method resolution isn't happening against the table at `getmetatable(conn)`.

```lua
function setup()
    -- Update the table at __index, not conn's metatable
    local mt = getmetatable(conn).__index

    function mt:receiveLine(...)
        local line, err = self:receive('*l')
        assert_string(line, err)
        return line
    end

    function mt:sendLine(...)
        local bytesSent, err = self:send(... .. '\n')
        assert_number(bytesSent, err)
        return bytesSent
    end
end
```

I was able to tease this out by testing to see if `__index` was pointing to `conn`'s metatable, which it wasn't:

```lua
assert_equal(getmetatable(conn), getmetatable(conn).__index)
```

Generically, if there is a `__newindex` handler on `getmetatable(conn)` that is intercepting new table entries, use `rawset()` on `__index`'s table.